Deployment Failure in Sitecore XM Cloud Environment - Solr Indexing Issue
We are currently facing an issue with our Sitecore XM Cloud deployment process, specifically within our test environment. During the deployment phase, we encounter a failure with the following log entries indicating issues:
14:50:32 Starting deployment of environment 'TEST'
14:50:41 Deployment configuration file has been created.
14:50:41 Winter is coming...
14:56:26 Deployment '1ifBovU1NAmEJpzsVJyoE' of environment 'TEST' has failed

Upon further investigation through the logs, we identified errors pointing towards problems with initializing the sitecore_master_index and related to Solr indexing. The relevant error messages are as follows:
ERROR [Index=sitecore_master_index] DefaultSolrSearchIndexesInitializer: Initialization has failed.
Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
Source: System
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at HttpWebAdapters.Adapters.HttpWebRequestAdapter.GetResponse()
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.GetResponse(IHttpWebRequest request)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
67952 09:05:07 ERROR ActionRunner: Execution is failed.

Additionally, health checks for our Solr indexes are returning unhealthy statuses with the message "Failed to get data from Solr server."
Based on these symptoms, it seems there might be a problem with how our sitecore and solr servers are set up or how they are connected.
Can anyone suggest steps to troubleshoot this issue or solutions to fix the deployment failure?
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

XM Cloud is a SaaS product, if you have issues with the deployments like this, please create a support ticket. You have no access to how the underlying services are provisioned, configured or created.
If you have custom code deployed to the CM, remove this and check the deployment. If it works without your custom code, investigate what you are customizing and why. In general you should not be deploying custom code to your CM platform.
For transparency, I am a Sitecore employee.

Thank you for your guidance. I've already opened a Sitecore support ticket and am seeking additional troubleshooting advice here.
